# Java - creating Web Service Request using JDOM - Header issue

Tags: java, web-services, header, jdom

I done many integrations using JDOM in Eclipse but for first time I have an issue because my SOAP XML message should contain and `HEADER` element wuth specific elements. This is my whole message:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:agi="http://agilent.parlayx.sms">
   <soapenv:Header>
         <cppass>test</cppass>
         <cpuname>test</cpuname>
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <agi:sendBulkSms>
            <address>tel:3876123456</address>
      </agi:sendBulkSms>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I created `BODY` structure using this:

```
Element top = new Element("sendBulkSms", agi);
Document jDoc = new Document(top);

Element address = new Element("address", agi);
address.setText("tel:3876123456");
top.addContent(address);
```

This works OK I did it many times before. But is it possible to create and header element of message uisng JDOM or not? Because as far as I know only BODY element can be defined but then my message will not be valid for web service request

Thank you, I will appreciate help

Comment: What webservice engine are you using?

Comment: integrations are done through the WebSphere Application Server

Comment: Then why don't you use the WAS WS Engine? It would be easier to code and maintain.

Comment: I must use JDOM. is it possible?please hints

Answer (score 0):

You are just creating standard XML there is no "header" you just have an Element named "Header" with namespace="soapenv". So in my opinion it should be like creating any other JDOM Element.